# How to atart chart multiple YAxis(s) to zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, scichart, scichart.js

I am using scichartJS

> "scichart": "^1.4.1607"

and I need to have my multiple Y-Axis(s) start at zero. And also the labels need to be aligned. Here is a screenshot of a different chart that does it correctly.

[Here is link to documentation on setting the visibleRange.](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/webframe.html#Axis%20Ranging%20-%20Setting%20and%20Getting%20VisibleRange.html)

[image: Example-Screenshot]

I am setting up my axis(s) in this function.

```
visibleRange ??
    const getYAxis = (x: YAxisData) =>
      new NumericAxis(wasmContext, {
        axisTitle: x.axisTitle,
        id: x.axisId,
        axisAlignment: setLocation(x),
        drawMinorTickLines: false,
        drawMajorTickLines: false,
        axisTitleStyle: {
          fontSize: 16,
          padding: Thickness.fromString('0 0 0 0'),
          color: theme.palette.grey['600'],
        },
      });

    yAxisData.forEach((x) => {
      const yAxis = getYAxis(x);
      yAxis.labelProvider.formatLabel = (dataValue) => {
        let value = formatNumberWithRounding(dataValue);
        if (value.includes(',')) value = `${value}k`;
        else value = `${Number(value).toFixed(2)}`;
        return value;
      };

      yAxis.drawMajorBands = false;
      yAxis.drawMinorGridLines = false;
      // yAxis.visibleRange = new NumberRange(5, 10);
      sciChartSurface.yAxes.add(yAxis);
    });
```

Which looks like this.

[image: Current Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure an axis always starts at zero in SciChart.js, you can try this code:

```
yAxis.visibleRangeChanged.subscribe(args => {
    if (args.visibleRange.min !== 0) {
        yAxis.visibleRange = new NumberRange(0, args.visibleRange.max);
    }
});
```

[See How to Listen to VisibleRange changes](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/Axis%20Ranging%20-%20How%20to%20Listen%20to%20VisibleRange%20Changes.html)

There is also an API in SciChart called the [axis.visibleRangeLimit](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/typedoc/classes/axisbase2d.html#visiblerangelimit) which can be used to clip autorange to a minimum and maximum. e.g. this:

```
// Ensure axis.visibleRange.min does not autorange outside 0
yAxis.visibleRangeLimit = new NumberRange(0, 99999999999);
```

However I think the first API will work better in your case.

Secondly about the alignment of ticks, you can use this API to define the spacing or interval of axis labels.

[Axis Ticks - Gridline and Label Spacing (Interval)](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/Axis%20Ticks%20-%20Gridline%20and%20Label%20Spacing%20(Interval).html)

```
yAxis.autoTicks = false; // Disable automatic tick calculation
yAxis.majorDelta = X; // set the spacing between major axis labels and gridlines
yAxis.minorDelta = Y; // set the spacing between minor axis gridlines
```

Finally there is a third more advanced API which provides unlimited customisation over the axis labels output, their spacing and coordinates. This API is called the [TickProvider](https://www.scichart.com/documentation/js/current/typedoc/classes/axisbase2d.html#tickprovider). How to use it:

```
yAxis.tickProvider.getMajorTicks = (minorDelta, majorDelta, visibleRange) => {
    // Force major gridlines and labels at these values always
    const outputTicks = [10,20,30,40,50];
    return outputTicks;
};
yAxis.tickProvider.getMinorTicks = (minorDelta, majorDelta, visibleRange) => {
    // Force minor gridlines at these values always
    const outputTicks = [5,15,25,35,45];
    return outputTicks;
};
```

This lets you return the exact numbers used for gridlines and labels. use this to customize SciChart as you wish!